# Graphing A Lima Bean Curve Leads To An Overlap Bump

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, geometry

I'm trying to graph this equation  `r=a(sin^3theta+cos^3theta)` or

`x = a * cos theta(sin^3theta+cos^3theta)`

`y = a * sin theta(sin^3theta+cos^3theta)`

Which comes out to be a lima bean. However, I'm having two issues. The first issue is that on the bottom right-center part of the bean there is a bump where it looks as if too many points were plotted and the graph overlapped and stopped abruptly.

The second problem is smoothing out the graph to be exported to a png to be manipulated later. I've kind of solved this by using `plt.save` fig to an SVG and the curves become very smooth. However, I'm left with that bump issue.

I know SciPy has an interpolate feature but I'm not fully sure yet on how to implement it or if it's worth it if I still have this weird bump.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, .01)[1:]
#t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)

x = 16 * np.cos(t)*((np.sin(t)**3) + np.cos(t)**3)
y = 13 * np.sin(t)*((np.sin(t)**3) + np.cos(t)**3)



fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi=72)
ax = fig.add_subplot(polar = False)

ax.plot(x, y, c=(1,0.2,0.5),lw=15)
plt.axis('off')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("filepath.svg", format = 'svg', dpi=300)
```

300 dpi isn't needed I was just testing how that affected the image.
Even though this isn't technically a circle it should still be 2 * Pi in order to complete a full rotation.
Adjusting the stop point to be 1 instead of 0 kind of fixes the bump but visually cuts it in half. Even if I used `3 * Pi` the bump is still there.

I've used Polar mode from `matplotlib` but it's limited in size and position. Using the parametric equations seems to be easier to configure.

[image: bean lol]

IIRC png is easier to manipulate in other python programs compared to SVG. But currently, as a png, it looks bad.

Comment: The line thickness of 15 is what most influences the weirdness of the bump. You could try to use something thinner.  To get a smoother png file, you can try a larger dpi. The smoothest values for `t` would be like `t = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2,500)`.

Comment: See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) about things going strange when trying to create parallel curves just via line thickness. In general, there is no one-fits-all solution to give an intuitive thickness to a curve.

Comment: Because this equation already creates the complete curve for theta over 180º.  Starting at -np.pi/2 lets the curve start at the lower left point, where the curve is most smooth. The start and end points create a little discontinuity in how the curve is displayed, so best to have them far away from the zone that interests you most.

Comment: What would be the math to add an extra curve at the top and bottom of the bean? Maybe that would be able to hide the bump.

Comment: I tried `ax.fill(np.r_[x * 1.01, x[::-1] * 0.95], np.r_[y * 1.01, y[::-1] * 0.95],  c=(1, 0.2, 0.5))`, but as the curve is not centered around 0,0 the thickness varies a lot. Also, some bump is just part of the mathematical curve, so there seems to be no need to hide it.

Comment: Hey thanks that looks cool and it works. 
Also If I change the theta formula to -np.pi/2 to -np.pi/1.5 at a line with it the bump is gone. 
And if I use your ax.fill with -np.pi/1.5 it fills the gap.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So a solution is to use
`t = np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2,500)` with `ax.plot(x, y, c=(1,0.2,0.5),lw=5)`.

Also thanks to @JohanC for
`ax.fill(np.r_[x * 1.01, x[::-1] * 0.95], np.r_[y * 1.01, y[::-1] * 0.95],  c=(1, 0.2, 0.5))`

Makes a cool looking design and doesn't have a bump as far as I could see.
I set the dpi to 720 which takes ~.5 seconds to process the image. I didn't time it that's just a guess.

I'm sure you could lower the dpi and use SciPy to interpolate the graph and then lower the dpi a bit but frankly I'm not sure how do that. I'll look into and if I find a good reason to use it instead of the solution above I'll come back and edit this post.